# Active Record - Rails 6, Having a model that two unrelated models use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

Lets say Im building a watch classifier system in rails 6. I have a model called material, material is use by both the watch body and bracelet.

the model would be something like this:

```
Material:
    description - text (gold, platinum, steel, silver etc)

Bracelet:
    style - text
    Material - has_many references (could be silver and rose gold etc)
    clasp - text
    etc

Watch
    brand - text
    Material - has_many references (case could be gold & white Gold etc)
    etc
```

As you can see both Bracelet and Watch are dependent on material in one to many, but material doesn't care or need to know about Watch or Bracelet so belongs_to: doesn't suit, nor does a polymorphic association

How do I model this in rails 6? and what would the migrations look like?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```rb
class CreateMaterials < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :materials do |t|
      t.integer :description, default: 0

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class Material < ApplicationRecord
  enum description: %i[gold, platinum, steel, silver] # etc

  has_and_belongs_to_many :watches
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bracelets
end





class CreateBracelets < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :bracelets do |t|
      t.text :style
      t.text :clasp
      # etc

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class Bracelet < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :materials
end




class CreateWatches < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :watches do |t|
      t.text :brand
      # etc

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class Watch < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :materials
end




class CreateMaterialsBracelets < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :materials_bracelets, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :material, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :bracelet, foreign_key: true
    end
  end
end

class CreateMaterialsWatches < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :materials_watches, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :material, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :watch, foreign_key: true
    end
  end
end
```

How do you like this decision? If something is wrong, then say it.